# Algebraic Manipulations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let a, b and c be such that $ a+b+c = 0 $ and

$ l^2 = \frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc} + \frac{b^2}{2b^2+ac} + \frac{c^2}{2c^2+ba} $

The what is the value of l

My approach : I could just put in the adequate values of a,b and c and check what comes out to be the value of $l$.

However I am looking for a more general approach to solve the following problem , I thought of using Lagrangian to solve , but that process looks to be too lengthy.

Any insight on what approach to follow would be welcome.

Comment: $$2a^2+bc=2a^2-b(a+b)=(2a+b)(a-b)=-(c-a)(a-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Setting $c=-a-b$ gives just
$$
(l-1)(l+1)=0.
$$